# java search for a particular word in a string

Tags: java, string

I have string like:

```
This.is.a.great.place.too.work.
```

(or)

```
This/is/a/great/place/too/work/
```

I want to see if this string has the word "place".

If they are word in a string I used contains("place").
as this is all one string I tried split but it is giving syntax error .
can you please let me know how to get it?

```
string.contains("place") works
String.split(".").contains("place")   Error
```

Comment: *"it is giving syntax error"* Copy/paste the error as an edit to the question.  Use code formatting. To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it simply like this.......

```
String s = "This/is/a/great/place/too/work/";
String ss = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work";

System.out.println(s.contains("place"));
System.out.println(ss.contains("place"));
```

Answer (score 2):

use `string.split("\\.").contains("place")` this should work. `.(dot)` is a reserved character in regular expression, You need to escape that by using `\\.`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to split with "//."

```
    String string = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.";
    System.out.println(string.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
String str = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.";
boolean exists = str.contains("place");
```

This checks to find the word **place** in a String and returns true if found, false if not

Comment: mine is a string like: This.is.a.great.place.too.work. so this wil not work with out split

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string.split(pattern);
String[] strings = s.split(".")
```

Split will give array of strings which are splitted based on the paramater .

you cannot apply contains on string array , instead use the following

```
boolean flag = string.contains("required_pattern");
```

Comment: can I not do Split and contains in the same line?>

Comment: no , split will give  array of strings as output. contains() can be used only on string

Comment: You can do something like Arrays.toString(str.split(".")).Contains("substring") but it looks really ugly.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to split the string in order to use the containts methode.

```
string str = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.";

boolean found = str.contains("substring"); // should return true or false
```

Alternative you can use the:

`str.indexOf("substring") > 0` to determine if the substring is in the string

To do this in one single line you can do something like:

```
Arrays.toString(str.split(".")).Contains("substring")
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using the `.contains` method, which I think is best, you seem to want to build a data structure and search through it. To do something like that, you will need to do this:

```
String str = "This.is.a.great.place.too.work.";
String[] splitWords = str.split("\\.");  //The . is a special character in regex language, thus needs to be escaped. Alternatively you could use \\W which will split the string where ever it finds a character which is not a letter, digit or underscore.
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(splitWords);
System.out.println(words.contains("place"));
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`indexOf(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method like so:

```
if (str.indexOf("place") > 0)
{
    System.out.println("String Exists");
}
```